# What could be causing water to drip from the relief valve of my new gas water heater, again?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I installed a brand new water heater about 4 months ago, noticed that that relief valve was dripping like crazy.  Checked the expansion tank and it was filled with water.  I replaced it with a brand new expansion tank only a few months old.  It was properly installed, got an accurate reading for water pressure from the city, set the air in the tank to a few pounds under that according to instructions.

Problem was fixed, the relief valve stopped dripping altogether for at least a month.  This recently started back up however and right in the middle of a home inspection no less (I am currently selling the home).  The home inspector included in his report that I have a faulty safety relief valve on my water heater and it needs to be replaced.  The buyers in turn demanded that I replace the safety relief valve despite the fact that I am not even sure if that is the problem.

I even explained to the home inspector and buyers when they were there that the water heater and expansion tank are brand new.  In your opinion is this a problem with the relief valve or the expansion tank or both?  Is it normal to buy a new water heater with a faulty relief valve?  Is it normal for a brand new expansion tank to already be taking on water?

**EDIT:**

I last measured this a few months ago, after opening faucet and releasing pressure from the water heater I got 30 psi.  The water heater temperature is between HOT and A, but the knob goes all the way up to C.  I filled up my NEW expansion tank to 28 psi and the dripping stopped completely for over a month.  My father in law seems to think that calcium can buildup around the relief valve and cause this dripping I am seeing and that it is more likely to be a problem with the relief valve than the brand new tank.

Comment: We still need your pressure and temperature readings from [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14076/new-gas-water-heater-dripping-relief-valve-have-expansion-tank-what-gives?rq=1)

Comment: There is a certain percentage of all new products that are faulty and slip through QA.  Is it normal? No, but it does occur with all types of products

Comment: @BMitch See my edits for the last readings I did.  I suppose it would help if I actually get a current reading when I get home

Comment: What is the pressure on the cold water inlet? Do you have a pressure reducing valve (PRV) on the inlet?

Comment: Tester may be right - the city pressure could be fluctuating from normal to high and the only way to even that out is to have a PRV for the whole house. It is a cheap part to rule that problem out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem was simple enough.  The expansion tank I installed that was only a few months old was completely filled with water.  I guess 28 psi is too much for a pressure tank that was tested and verified for up to 100psi.

Now where did I put that warranty card? :)

Comment: Careful, sometimes warranties are void if not installed by a professional. Read the fine print carefully before you call, or you might be disappointed.

Comment: @Tester101 It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: I think that the expansion tank needs to be charged to slightly above the system water pressure (normally around 50-60 PSI). When undercharged, it can cause the bladder to fail and also it will not do its job (causing the PRV to expel water).

Answer (score 1):

The expansion tank needs to be charged with an air pressure equal to your system water pressure. Normally, this pressure is in the 50-60 PSI range. Too low of a pre-charge will cause premature bladder failure and also will cause the tank to not do its duty as an expansion tank.

The problem could also be a failure of the pressure relief valve.

Comment: Yeah, this happened to me recently when I did the yearly tank drain. I opened the pressure relief valve to bleed air in the tank during draining, and when I closed it, it didn't seal properly due to scale fouling the valve. Replaced it with a new valve from Home Depot and all was well again. MAKE SURE TO REPLACE WITH SAME PRESSURE/TEMP RATING!